# Bar label is getting cut from the plot and mai/omi parameters aren't fixing the issue

Tags: r, charts, label, histogram

I put labels on my bars, but the first one is falling out of the chart. I tried applying mai= and omi= parameters to no avail. Below is the code I'm using to create the chart:

```
hist(airquality$Ozone, col = "lightblue4", main="", , labels = TRUE,yaxt='n',ylab = "", xlab="Ozone (ppb)")
title("Ozone quantity in New York in 1978 (count)")
```

[image]

Comment: If you expand the plot (by clicking on `Zoom` in Rstudio) it shows the label correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the **y axis** limits with the argument *ylim*

```
hist(airquality$Ozone,
     col = "lightblue4", main="",ylim = c(0,40) ,
     labels = TRUE,yaxt='n',ylab = "", xlab="Ozone (ppb)")
```